# Binding click event to appended link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a lightbox that uses jQuery's $.ajax to retrieve data.

If i get back no data, then I append a "no data found" message to my list, and a link to reset the search parameters.  Basically I'm trying to add a .click() event to a link that I've appended.

**The problem is that the function is running immediately, not waiting for a click event.**

So when I execute this, the "no data found message" appears briefly and then is replaced by the default results.

```
function getImages(/* parameters ... */) {
    // other code...
    // if no results:
    $('div#imageLightBox ul.thumbList').append('<li>Sorry, no images found. <a href="#" id="clearSearchLink">Clear search</a>.</li>');
    $('a#clearSearchLink').click(new function() {
        alert("clearSearchLink");
        // code that resets the search parameters ...
        getImages('', '', $('#lightBoxPageSize').val(), 1); // <-- calls the function that contains this code.
    });
};
```

Comment: Also, I tried using the .live event handler instead, defining it before I ever added the link - the exact same thing happened, the code executed before the button was ever clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> click(new function() {

Just ‘function’.

This is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/function_Operator), not a constructor; ‘new Function()’ with the capital F is the explicit [constructor version](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/function.htm#1213954), which you generally don't want to use as it takes and evaluates a string argument every call, which is pretty yucky (and slower).

What is happening is the function expression is creating a new function, then the ‘new’ operator is calling it with a newly-created Object as `this` (which is what `new` actually does).

Comment: an anonymous function expression?

Comment: Indeed. Anonymous function expressions are used an awful lot by code in the jQuery style.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I didn't see that! Long day I guess. Thanks.